# How to create a fixed length list

Tags: python-3.x, list, content-length

I am trying to append a list with values received from a websocket so that I only get the last values from the previous 5 minutes (300 seconds, instead of 10 in my example). So far I have used :

```
      D=[None]*10 #whose length returns 10 then 11, 12 and so on as I update it with new values
```

and

```
      D = []

      for i in range(10):

      D.append(i) #whose length returns 10 then 20, 30 and so on as I update it with new values
```

Any ideas on how I may proceed? If not possible I was thinking of maybe creating a list that is updated for 5 min then is cleared and updated for the next 5 min and so on. On that note, is it possible start appending the list at a specific time like 13h till 13h05 then restart?
Thanks,
Lrd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(maxlen=5)
>>> d.extend([1,2,3,4])
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4], maxlen=5)
>>> d.append(5)
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], maxlen=5)
>>> d.append(9)
>>> d
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 9], maxlen=5) # the list shifted to the left
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much. On that note, is it possible to start appending the list at a specific time like 13h till 13h05, empty the list then restarts?